# disable checkbox/textbox dynamically after insert

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to disable checkbox(which I fetched using while loop in php) after form submit. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<td><?php echo $num['roomno']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $num['regno']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $num['pname']; ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="diet" id="diet" value="<? echo $num['regno'];?>"
<?php if(($regno!="") && ($thiss == $regno)) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> />
</td>
```

This is the php section to get the value from checked checkbox. I dont know if I'm doing the right way.

```
<?
$regno = isset($_REQUEST['diet'])?$_REQUEST['diet']:"";
if(isset($regno)) {
$selec = "select regno from roomlist where regno='".$regno."'";
$sql = mysqli_query($con,$selec);
if(!$sql) {
    echo "Error : ".mysqli_error($sql);
    exit();
}
$num = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$thiss = $num['regno'];
}
```

Comment: What is `'checkbox==checked'` ?

Comment: where is your form?

Comment: Show us details?

Comment: The portion `checkbox==checked` is incorrect and where is the form tag ?